# How to help the automated fuzzing community?

Tags: fuzzing

I can see there are great tools to do automated fuzzing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing

ex.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_fuzzy_lop_(fuzzer)

But how can a non-programmer help these groups?

Are there any BOINC-like projects, where average people just run an application/BOINC project that helps different softwares with fuzzing?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? What do you intend to help?

Comment: You honestly don't need to be particularly experienced with programming to help with fuzzing. Even if you don't find a security vulnerability, finding a crash in a popular application and reporting it can be very helpful. AFL will give you the input file to perfectly reproduce the crash, so you can analyze it yourself or submit it to others for analysis.